# Parsing through 'mixed' dicitonary

Tags: dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

supposed I have the following dictionary with standard and nested key value pairs:

```py
dictionary = {'fruta1': 'Pera',
                  'fruta2': {'fruta3': 'aguacates', 'fruta4':'limones'}
              }
```

How can I iterate through all the items with a dictionary comprehension?
the following code throws this error:
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str"
if I try this loop:

```py
texto = '\n'.join(key + ":\n" + value for key, value in dictionary.items())
print(texto)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for fixing the code. Now, that solutions works with the print function. But what if I want to pass the key value pairs as a variable for another function? I am not mistaken ( and I may be), if one runs the code using 'x = ' instead of "print" the recursive function will update the variable with only one set of values, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off with a recursion:

```py
dictionary = {'fruta1': 'Pera',
              'fruta2': {'fruta3': 'aguacates', 'fruta4':'limones'}
             }

def print_key_val(dic):
   for k,v in dic.items():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
         print_key_val(v)
      else:
         print(f"{k}:\n{v}")

print_key_val(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
fruta1:
Pera
fruta3:
aguacates
fruta4:
limones
```